# How to change the color of material of an object individually if the material is shared

Tags: three.js

I have an array of 3d objects loaded from collada file. When I'm trying to change the color of material of an object from the array, color changes for all the objects in the array.

arr[5].material.color.setHex(0x00CC00); will update color for all objects in array. I assume it happens because the share one instance of material since objects are the same. Is there anyway to apply color individually? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way it works right now you need to have a different material per object. In the future maybe `Object3D` will have a `color` property.

Comment: Thanks for clarification! Especially from the author of Three.js! :) Big honour! Thanks an awesome library, you guys doing tremendous job!